# Using deferred objects inside Twisted applications

Tags: python, twisted

I feel like I am not understanding some things in writing Twisted applications (.tac files). Using deferred objects in .py scripts is easy by just calling `reactor.run()` at the end, but I have not seen `reactor.run()` used in any twisted application sample code.

Can someone explain:

1. why `reactor.run()` is not called in twisted applications (or if this is an erroneous conclusion)
2. how I can use deferred objects inside a twisted application perhaps without calling `reactor.run()`
3. and general differences in writing twisted scripts vs applications.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 1. Why is `reactor.run()` not called in example `.tac` files?

`.tac` files are meant to be loaded by the "`twistd`" command-line tool, which runs the reactor for you.

Running the reactor is something that's done once, by whatever bit of code is serving as the main-point for your program.  Most Twisted code is effectively a plug-in of some kind, meant to operate in the context of a larger system.

In the particular case of `.tac` files, they are never meant to be run as stand-alone Python programs: their job is to produce an `Application` object (with an attached bunch of `Service` objects) that get started up when the reactor runs.  It's important that the `tac` file itself not do much work on its own, because (for example) the `Service` implementations in question may need to separate code which needs to run privileged and unprivileged, which is an exacting process; if work is performed in the `.tac` itself, it may be haphazardly executed as the wrong user.

## 2. How I can use `Deferred`s inside a Twisted application, without calling `reactor.run()`?

`Deferred` is simply a mechanism for managing chains of callbacks.  You don't need to call `reactor.run()`, or indeed, even have a reactor at all, to use them.  For example:

```
>>> from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
>>> d = Deferred()
>>> def hello(result):
...     print "'d' was fired:", result
...     return result + 3
... 
>>> d.addCallback(hello)
<Deferred at ...>
>>> print d
<Deferred at ...>
>>> d.callback(7)
'd' was fired: 7
>>> print d
<Deferred at ... current result: 10>
```

That said, many APIs that return a `Deferred` need the reactor to do some work in order to eventually call `.callback()` on it.  For example, if you do ...

```
>>> from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
>>> from twisted.internet import reactor
>>> deferLater(reactor, 1.0, lambda: 20).addCallback(hello)
<Deferred at ...>
>>>
```

... you'll be sitting around forever waiting for that to fire unless somebody runs the reactor.  Nothing will print until that happens.

But, if the reactor is already running - for example, if you were running this interactive example in `python -m twisted.conch.stdio` rather than `python`, you would see that `Deferred` get called back a second later, because that interactive prompt is already running the reactor.

## 3. What are the differences between Twisted scripts vs. applications?

These aren't really formally separated terms.  Any Python script can potentially import code from Twisted and use it any way it wants to, so it's hard to say that any particular property applies to "scripts" except that they are computer programs :-).

If by Twisted Application you mean a `.tac` file or a plugin, the difference is that this kind of code is separated out into the part the builds the service (the code at the top level in your `tac` file or plugin) and the part that actually does the work (`privilegedStartService`/`startService`/`stopService` implementations of the services that said top-level code sets up).  Also, code that runs in this context (i.e. is driven by `twistd`) does not need to run the reactor itself, since one will be set up and run by `twistd` itself.  Such code must also therefore be careful to avoid importing `twisted.internet.reactor`, because `twistd` provides the ability to use *different* reactors (`select`, `poll`, `epoll`, `kqueue`, etc) and importing the reactor yourself before `twistd` has a chance to set it up will break this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the how `tac` files work. The API that led me to ask this question was the `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` API that returns a deferred for a sql query. I found that it would only go through when `reactor.run()` was called. How can I add the query to the reactor loop created by `twistd`?

Comment: Three questions on a single stackoverflow question may be enough. :)